# Adding Module dependency Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to add the dependency for a multimodule gradle project
**The parent Module is -MicroOne.
Child modules are-controller, service**

Build.gradle of MicroOne is

```
group = 'com.test'
```

Settings.gradle of MicroOne is

```
rootProject.name = 'microone'
include 'service'
include 'controller'
```

Build.gradle for the service module is

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}


group ='com.test'
version= '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project (':controller')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

}
```

And for Controller is

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.test'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am not able to add the dependency from Service module to the Controller module, I am not able to import a class which is present in the Service module to the Controller module

Comment: you already have dependency of controller in service `   implementation project (':controller')` hence its not allowing due to cyclic dependency.

Comment: Yes I should have added implementation project (':service') in the controller module